# Convert rows into RDD in pyspark

Tags: lambda, pyspark

I want to produce a file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nUkH.png) image with the below dataset.
The result is the result of filtering a dataframe with this line:

```
df1 = df0.rdd.filter(lambda x: 'VS' in x.MeterCategory)
  .map(lambda x: [x.vId,x.Meters]).take(2)
```

DataSet of rows:

```
[ABCD1234, Row(0=6.0, 10=None, 100=None, 1000=None, 10000=None, 1000000=None, 100000000=None, 10235=None, 1024=None)]
[WXYZ9999,Row(0=40.0, 10=None, 100=None, 1000=None, 10000=None, 1000000=None, 100000000=None, 10235=None, 1024=None)]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nUkH.png]

I've been trying with some approaches, that I found in this forum, but I cannot achieve the result.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, both solutions works.
but now, the dev. team add the field names with .(dot), and pyspark is unable to find the field name.
So far, I do not know if using for .. in ... will reduce the performance in the worker nodes, even if this instruction will handle it by nodes.
the cluster is a microsoft hdinsight with default configuration.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
df = sc.parallelize([('ABCD1234',6.0,'None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None'),
                     ('WXYZ9999',40.0,'None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None')]).toDF(['Id','0','10','100','1000','10000','1000000','100000000','10235','1024'])
```

You can pivot the data using the following snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

kvp = F.explode(F.array([F.struct(F.lit(c).cast(StringType()).alias("Key"), F.col(c).cast(StringType()).alias("Value")) for c in df.columns if c!='Id'])).alias("kvp")
df_pivoted = df.select(['Id'] + [kvp]).select(['Id'] + ["kvp.Key", "kvp.Value"])
df_pivoted.show()
```

And you can output the data to a single CSV by converting the Dataframe to pandas:

```
df_pivoted.toPandas().to_csv('e:/output.csv',index=False,header = 'true', sep='|')
```

This gives as output:

```
Id|Key|Value
ABCD1234|0|6.0
ABCD1234|10|None
ABCD1234|100|None
ABCD1234|1000|None
ABCD1234|10000|None
ABCD1234|1000000|None
ABCD1234|100000000|None
ABCD1234|10235|None
ABCD1234|1024|None
WXYZ9999|0|40.0
WXYZ9999|10|None
WXYZ9999|100|None
WXYZ9999|1000|None
WXYZ9999|10000|None
WXYZ9999|1000000|None
WXYZ9999|100000000|None
WXYZ9999|10235|None
WXYZ9999|1024|None
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.

Firstly please note, what you are referring to df1 is an RDD not a dataframe

You can create that RDD with the dataset you mentioned as follows to try the things out.

Please note that I have used '_' as prefix for your column names as a pure number cant be used as a column name directly.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row

>>> row1 = Row(_0=6.0, _10=None, _100=None, _1000=None, _10000=None, _1000000=None, 
           _100000000=None, _10235=None, _1024=None)
>>> row2 = Row(_0=40.0, _10=None, _100=None, _1000=None, _10000=None, _1000000=None,
           _100000000=None, _10235=None, _1024=None)

>>> yourStartDataset = sc.parallelize([
                                         ['ABCD1234',row1],
                                         ['WXYZ9999',row2]
                                      ])
```

Now your dataset looks like this

```
>>> yourStartDataset.take(2)

[['ABCD1234',
  Row(_0=6.0, _10=None, _100=None, _1000=None, _10000=None, _1000000=None, _100000000=None, _10235=None, _1024=None)],
 ['WXYZ9999',
  Row(_0=40.0, _10=None, _100=None, _1000=None, _10000=None, _1000000=None, _100000000=None, _10235=None, _1024=None)]]
```

Now the below line will do the magic

```
>>> yourStartDataset.flatMapValues(lambda v: v.asDict().items()).map(lambda (a, (b, c)): (a, b, c)).collect()

[('ABCD1234', '_1000000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_100000000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_100', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_10000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_0', 6.0),
 ('ABCD1234', '_1000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_10', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_10235', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '_1024', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_1000000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_100000000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_100', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_10000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_0', 40.0),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_1000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_10', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_10235', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '_1024', None)]
```

Or, if you want to get only numeral part of your columns, the below will do

```
>>> yourStartDataset.flatMapValues(lambda v: v.asDict().items()).map(lambda (a, (b, c)): (a, b[1:], c)).collect()

[('ABCD1234', '1000000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '100000000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '100', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '10000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '0', 6.0),
 ('ABCD1234', '1000', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '10', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '10235', None),
 ('ABCD1234', '1024', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '1000000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '100000000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '100', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '10000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '0', 40.0),
 ('WXYZ9999', '1000', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '10', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '10235', None),
 ('WXYZ9999', '1024', None)]
```

Hope this is helpful